# Can't access Xbox LIVE in GTA IV

Tags: xbox-network, grand-theft-auto-iv

I have an xbox360 and every time I play Grand Theft Auto IV and the go to multiplayer, it says "your gamer profile does not have the correct permissions to access Xbox LIVE functionality".  I have tried changing my privacy settings to adult, but it sti, as far as I'm aware.

What's going on?

Comment: Do you have a paid Xbox Live subscription?

Answer (score 1):

For every game on Xbox Live you will need a paid Xbox Live Gold subscription. Make sure you have that.

If you do have a subscription, you might be banned from playing GTA 4 online, if you misbehaved online. If it is your first time playing online beeing banned is unlikely.

If none of the above seems to be true, you might want to contact [Microsoft in their support forum](http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_support/default.aspx) or [Rockstar Games on their support site](http://support.rockstargames.com/home).